# Install and switch from Java 6 and 7

Tags: macos, java-7, java-6

I'm new on mac and I need to install both Java 6 and Java 7.
My Mac's version is Mac OS X Lion 10.7.5 (11G63)

The problem is I have found already installed Java 7 and I need to install Java 6 and switch between them because I have some projects needed 6 and others need 7.
I normally go on oracle web site and download the version's Java that I need to install on Linux or Windows.

The problem is that I couldn't find the version for Mac on http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javase6-419409.html#jdk-6u45-oth-JPR

Could someone explain me how I can get Java 6 and how I can switch between them?
Thanks a million

Comment: 1. welcome to SO. This doesn't seem to be related to programming. You might be better off at `Ask Different`. 2. I'm not into java at all but I guess it is backwards compatible. So you only need the most recent Java version available.

Comment: Thanks HAS, I'm a developer and I need both version of Java how I explained before. The problem is not if they are compatible I want just install Java 6 and switch between java 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to Mac world !! You need to download Java from this [site](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572) and install it on your system. After that, open your terminal and type

```
javac -version
```

You will see that it still shows your java version 1.7.

What you need to do next is using `java_home` to check the path of the java 1.6

```
$ /usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.6
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0_45-b06-451.jdk/Contents/Home
$ /usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.7
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_51.jdk/Contents/Home
```

So, whenever you need 1.6 or 1.7, you can set the path of the particular version in `/User/<your-account>/.bash_profile`. For example:

```
export JAVA_HOME="/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0_45-b06-451.jdk/Contents/Home"
# export JAVA_HOME="/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_51.jdk/Contents/Home"
```

Comment: Thanks bubuzz, it works great, I can't give you a reputation because I didn't have yet 15.